# Is it possible to sort images by color regardless of the file type in windows 10?

Tags: images, colors, sorting

Basically, I have a folder full of color and black and white line drawings. Now I only want to keep the line drawings and I don't want to keep the color images. I could make a script to read each file and check if they are grayscale images but some black and white line art images can be color images as well. Is it possible to sort these images in the folder with or without 3rd party tools?

Comment: I have a [scala script](https://pastebin.com/tW3Rz5mH) that can sort images by color. It moves all images in the current folder into one of three sub folders depending on whether it thinks the image contains a significant amount of color.

Comment: there's no native support in any OS I've known of, so the only way is using a 3rd party software

Comment: @SpiderPig why not write that up as an answer?